# Java/Scala Bounded Generics and type inference mismatch

Tags: java, scala, generics

Coming from a Java background, I understand that this does not compile.

```
public static class SuperClass {}
public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {}

public static <T, U extends T> U returnSub(T sup, U sub) {
    return sub;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass parent = new SuperClass();
    SubClass child = new SubClass();

    returnSub(parent, child);
    returnSub(child, parent); // Java doesn't like that
}
```

The last line produces a compiler error (EDIT : at least on jdk1.6.0_65) it does :

> Bound mismatch: The generic method returnSub(T, U) of type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Test.SubClass, Test.SuperClass). The inferred type Test.SuperClass is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

So, I got surprised, that this seems to work in Scala. I wrote the sample code below (which as far as I can tell, expresses the same "logic") :

```
class SuperClass
class SubClass extends SuperClass

def returnSub[Type, SubType <: Type](supArg: Type, subArg: SubType): SubType = {
  subArg
}

override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val parent = new SuperClass()
  val child = new SubClass()

  val iAmOkWithThat: SubClass = returnSub(parent, child)
  val iDontGetThat: SuperClass = returnSub(child, parent)
}
```

I *guess* the Scala compiler is smart enough to say "OK, `child` is an instance of `SubClass`, but I can't invoke `returnSub` if I say that, so let me try if I consider `child` as a `SuperClass` instance, and, well, it works, so let's do that".

Is that what's going on (and if so, can you point to a language specification about that) ? Or maybe my Scala "conversion" is not equivalent to my Java code ?

Thanks!

Comment: It should work for both Java and Scala, because `T` and `U` can both be `SuperClass`. I tried your Java program and it compiled and ran perfectly using `jdk1.8.0_25`. What makes you think Java doesn't like it?

Comment: I only got an old Java right there. That maybe why (jdk 1.6.0_65). Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Type inference has improved massively since 1.6. You should get it to work on all versions from Java 1.5 onwards by doing `ThisClass.<SuperClass, SuperClass>returnSub(child, parent);`.

Comment: Running on the same JDK, the scala compiler (2.11.7) does not need extra inference info. Still, your suggestion indeed it works and makes the 1.6 javac "happy". Thanks for pointing this. Feel free to redact this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work for both languages because `T` and `U` can both be `SuperClass`. With Java 1.8 your code compiles without problems. Type inference has improved greatly since generics were introduced, but you can get this to work on all versions of Java from 1.5 onwards by writing

```
ThisClass.<SuperClass, SuperClass>returnSub(child, parent);
```

You need to provide explicit type arguments like this much less frequently now.

As for why you don't get the same issues with Scala, I'm afraid I can't answer that as I'm don't know Scala at all.